# Access Violation reading location 0x00000002

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, exception

My code getting the below Error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00b09736 in CChatClient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000002.

I wouldn't be able to post the whole code so pasting the part of code from where error is coming..

```
> static void run_thread(void *args)
    {
        CThreadRunnable *pRunnable = static_cast<CThreadRunnable*>(args);
        int* actual_arg = (int *)args;
        if (*actual_arg)
        {
            PRINTD "value of arg=" << *actual_arg << std::endl;
            pRunnable->run(actual_arg);
        }
    }
```

On 5th line that run time exception is coming.
I am unable to debug this error on visual studio 10.
Can somebody please help, how to debug this kinda error on visual studio compiler.

Thanks,
Ravindra Gupta

Comment: Add your code that causes this error here.

Comment: Looks like a null pointer. Although that is all I can say without code.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @RavindraGupta if you cannot debug, you should add some traces/logs so as to determine to the closest point where things go right, and when things go wrong. That will help you target the portion of code that could be the source of the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by, "unable to debug?"

Comment: @herohuyongtao:i added the part of code can u please look again.

Comment: Can you post the code that you create the thread?

Comment: Where do you call `run_thread()`?

Comment: There's a number of places where your code might access an uninitialized or wrongly casted pointer.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Either `args` points to a `CThreadRunnable`, or it points to an `int` - it can't be both. Yet you go ahead and cast it both ways.

Comment: HANDLE hThreadHndr = CreateThread (NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&CChatClient::run_thread, (LPVOID)SEND, 0, NULL);
 
This is the way i am calling the run_thread. @drescherjm

Comment: The signature of `run_thread` is not correct for `CreateThread` (which is why you had to use a cast to get it to compile). It must be `DWORD WINAPI run_thread(void*)` (the `WINAPI` part is particularly important). Also, what is `SEND`? Is it `CThreadRunnable*`, or `int*`, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (*actual_arg)
```

If this line caused the error, then actual_arg is 2 and you try to handle it as a pointer and dereference it. You are not allowed to peek at the memory address of 2 and get an access violation.

Guessing, I'd say you passed your variable instead of it's address to the function.

Edit:

Your signature is wrong.

```
static void run_thread(void *args)
```

[Correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa964928%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) would be

```
static DWORD run_thread(void* args)
```

Comment: HANDLE hThreadHndr = CreateThread (NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&CChatClient::run_thread, (LPVOID)SEND, 0, NULL);
 
This is the way i am calling the run_thread.

Comment: @Ravindra If you have to cast you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Debug->Exceptions. When check both check-boxes for "System Runtime Exceptions" (name might be something else, I don't remember exact name).

Comment: What does this do? How does this help the OP? Why should the OP do this?

Comment: "Can somebody please help, how to debug this kinda error on visual studio compiler." It is exactly the way to debug crashes if place isn't known. Question was edited by OP.